# Scipy Optimize custom cost function

Tags: python, scipy

(Sorry cost function is probably the wrong term)

I'm trying to fit some mass spectrometry data where I know what most of the peaks are but not all. Consequently I expect there to be a positive residual when I'm done. Looks like most of the scipy fitting algorithms are simply trying to minimize the rms residual so I'm not seeing a way to penalize negative residuals more then positive.

To make this clear here is some simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gaussian(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2.0 / (2.0 * sigma**2))


def get_y_with_noise(x, peaks):
    """Return your input spectrum with some lazy shot like noise."""
    n = len(x)
    y = np.zeros(n)
    for peak in peaks:
        y += gaussian(x, *peak)
    # Add some noise.
    y += np.random.randn(n) * 0.05 * np.sqrt(y)
    y[np.where(y < 0.0)] = 0.0
    return y


def fit_peaks_and_plot(x, peaks):
    """Generate the fit some peaks."""

    y = get_y_with_noise(x, peaks)
    # Make a really good guess of starting params.
    p0 = peaks[0]

    # Fit the data.
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(gaussian, x, y, p0=p0)

    # Plot residuals. Look works great.
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, *popt))
    plt.plot(x, y - gaussian(x, *popt))
    plt.show()


# Define our data range.
x = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.01)
# Some peaks that separate nicely.
peaks_1 = [[1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.5, 5.0, 1.0]]
# Some peaks that are too close for comforter.
peaks_2 = [[1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.5, 2.0, 1.0]]

# Set up some peak.
fit_peaks_and_plot(x, peaks_1)
fit_peaks_and_plot(x, peaks_2)
```

The first set of peaks separate nicely.
[image]
The second set of peaks overlap so we try to fit a non-gaussian with a gaussian and are left with significant negative residuals. 
[image]

I would like to add to modify the cost function to penalize negative residuals more then positive.

I believe that in my example curve_fit is trying to minimize:

```
np.sum( ((f(xdata, *popt) - ydata) / sigma)**2 )
```

As a toy model you could instead try to minimize:

```
weighted_res = (f(xdata, *popt) - ydata) / sigma
weighted_res[np.where(weighted_res < 0.0)] *= 10.0
np.sum(weighted_res)
```

Clearly I can define a function that returns the weighted_res and try to fit it to zero, but that seems like a very round about way to do this.